# How to check if Configuration Section exists in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core, app-config, appsettings

How can you check if a configuration section exists in the `appsettings.json` in .NET Core?

Even if a section doesn't exist, the following code will always return an instantiated instance.

e.g.

```
var section = this.Configuration.GetSection<TestSection>("testsection");
```

Comment: That's what I'm using. In my example this.Configuration is IConfigurationRoot which has a GetSection method. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Query the children of Configuration and check if there is any with the name "testsection"

```
var sectionExists = Configuration.GetChildren().Any(item => item.Key == "testsection"));
```

This should return true if "testsection" exists, otherwise false.

Comment: which library are you using for the `configuration`?

Comment: ASP.NET core already has an inbuilt support for several configuration providers in the package  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.  Refer to [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 62):

Since .NET Core 2.0, you can also call the [ConfigurationExtensions.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.exists?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationExtensions_Exists_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationSection_) extension method to check if a section exists.

```
var section = this.Configuration.GetSection("testsection");
var sectionExists = section.Exists();
```

Since `GetSection(sectionKey)` [never returns null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration.getsection?view=aspnetcore-2.1), you can safely call `Exists` on its return value.

It is also helpful to read this documentation on [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 15):

In **.Net 6**, there is a new extension method for this:

[ConfigurationExtensions.GetRequiredSection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getrequiredsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Throws `InvalidOperationException` if there is no section with the given key.

---

Further, if you're using the `IOptions` pattern with `AddOptions<TOptions>()`, the [ValidateOnStart()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderextensions.validateonstart?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) extension method was also added in .Net 6 to be able to specify that validations should run at startup, instead of only running when the `IOptions` instance is resolved.

With some questionable cleverness you can combine it with `GetRequiredSection()` to make sure a section actually exist:

```cs
// Bind MyOptions, and ensure the section is actually defined.
services.AddOptions<MyOptions>()
    .BindConfiguration(nameof(MyOptions))
    .Validate<IConfiguration>((_, configuration)
        => configuration.GetRequiredSection(nameof(MyOptions)) is not null)
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

Comment: You saved my life with this one, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DataAnnotations`

```cs
builder.Services.AddOptions<AppSettings>()
    .BindConfiguration(nameof(AppSettings))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()//
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

That will make sure the data annotations works:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class AppSettings()
{
    [Required]
    public required string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Will only work if `AppSettings` and `MyProperty` are set:

```json
"AppSettings":{
    "MyProperty ":"non-empty string"
  }
```